# Filtering data by start date and end date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel consisting of start date and the end date in columns.
I can filter out the start date and the end date
but I am not happy with the filtering as it just gives me only the date in between of these two:

for eg in pandas if I use start date - 5/3/2019 and end date as - 5/13/2019

it excludes the entries having start date of 4/25/2019 and end date - 5/10/2019.

I want such entries to appear if the entry is has an end date between the start and the end date

Now this problem is solved with the following code :

```
df['QC START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QC START DATE'])
df = df[(((df['QC START DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) & (df['QC START DATE'] <= endateEn.get())) | ((df['QC END DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) & (df['QC END DATE'] <= endateEn.get())))]
```

Now another problem arises is that when I filter the end date it gives me results exceeding the end date .e.g. - if my end date is 5/29/2019 it gives me results till 5/31/2019. I just want the results to remain within or less than the end date

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This does not work the filters are just haywire